# Add random integer to total?

Tags: c++

I am working on a blackjack-like program. I initially generate a random pair of cards and store the total of the numbers. If the user wishes to, another card must be generated, and the new total needs to be updated. Here is the program so far:

```cpp
/*
Cortez Phenix
The 25th of January, 2021
CS10B, Mr. Harden
Assignment 2.1

This program uses...
*/

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(nullptr)));

    string card_choice;
    string repeat_choice;
    int num_1 = rand()%10+1;
    int num_2 = rand()%10+1;
    int total = num_1 + num_2;

    cout << "First Cards: " << num_1 << ", " << num_2;
    cout << "\nTotal: " << total << "\n\n";

    do{
    cout << "Do you want another card? (y/n) ";
    cin >> card_choice;
    }
    while (card_choice == "y" && total += rand()%10+1);

    if (card_choice == "y")
        cout << "\nplay more\n";

    if (card_choice == "n")
        cout << "\nDo you want to play again?\n";


    /*cin >> choice;
    total += choice;
    cout << total;*/

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled, there is an error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment. How do I properly add the numbers and update the variable? Thank you!

Comment: Hint:  What does operator `=+` do (if it exists)?

Comment: Since C++ is case-sensitive, "Y" is different than "y".  You may want something like: `card_choice = tolower(card_choice);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add brackets for the addition and assignment operator as following. (also I think you mean `+=` instead of `=+` but I didn't change it in the code.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(nullptr)));

    string card_choice;
    string repeat_choice;
    int num_1 = rand()%10+1;
    int num_2 = rand()%10+1;
    int total = num_1 + num_2;

    cout << "First Cards: " << num_1 << ", " << num_2;
    cout << "\nTotal: " << total << "\n\n";

    do{
    cout << "Do you want another card? (y/n) ";
    cin >> card_choice;
    }
    while (card_choice == "y" && (total =+ rand()%10+1));

    if (card_choice == "y")
        cout << "\nplay more\n";

    if (card_choice == "n")
        cout << "\nDo you want to play again?\n";


    /*cin >> choice;
    total += choice;
    cout << total;*/

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cool, you copied over the same syntax error, `total =+ rand()%10+1`.